# how to shuffle word from comma separated?

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode, shuffle

how to shuffle word from comma separated?

example my code

```
//code1
$name1 =  explode(',', 'one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten');
$name1 = shuffle('trim', $name1 );
echo $name1;

//code2
$name2 =  ('one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten');
$name2 = shuffle('trim', $name2 );

echo $name2;
```

i want something like this

Output1

```
 two one eight three  six four ten five seven nine
```

Output2

```
 eight, five, two, three,  six, four, ten, one, seven, nine,
```

thank you.

Comment: What do you want the output to be? Like output 2?

Comment: i want name1 Like output 1 and name2 Like output 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
<?php
$name = explode(', ', 'one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten');
shuffle($name);

$output1 = implode(', ', $name);
$output2 = implode(' ', $name);
?>
```

Comment: `Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home3/mysite/public_html/test.php on line 3`